# Visual Studio 2017 - ASP.NET changes to .cshtml are not being reflected

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have an ASP.NET application that was working fine yesterday. Suddenly, changes made to `.cshtml` files are not being reflected on the IIS Express server. I have done the following:

- Restarted the computer
- Clear the cache on the browser and disabled cache (while DevTools is open)
- I uninstalled and reinstalled IIS Express
- Changed code in other files
- Have Visual Studio running with admin privileges
- Used `Ctrl + F5` to force changes in the browser

However, none of these steps have solved the problem. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: If you open the debug console in your browser and/or view source in your browser, do you see the changes?

Comment: Can you check iis express to project path ? maybe use incorrect folder path.

Comment: Disable caching programmatically just to be sure is not related to caching first.

Comment: @MichaelArmes didn't think to do that, just checked, I do not see the changes in the browser debug console

Comment: @ibrahimatay how can I check the IIS project path? I assumed it would be the same path as the project

Comment: Are you using IIS Express to run it, or IIS? If IIS, right-click on your site in IIS and pick "Explore". That should open the file system path of where your project is.

Comment: @MichaelArmes I am using IIS Express to run the project right from Visual Studio

Comment: Can you try to change iis port ?

Comment: Maybe cleaning the solution, and re-building?

Comment: @ibrahimatay just changed the port number, same problem

Comment: @MichaelArmes I'm a pretty new programmer, are there any risks to cleaning?

Comment: I know it maybe a long shot but, are you coding in the temp version of the file? IF you hover over the cshtml tab, can you see temp/tmp in the path?

Comment: @JamesS I actually was coding in the temp version of the file... that's embarrassing. Thank you, and everyone else!

Comment: Good catch, @JamesS! I didn't think about that. :)

Comment: No problem, Sometimes if you have a breakpoint in a cshtml or your code fails in there, visual studio will bring up that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was making changes in a temporary version of the file. Once I started editing the actual file, changes were reflected on the IIS Express server.

Thank you everyone for your help!